# Is there a standard approach for handling pub/sub message versioning?

Tags: versioning, publish-subscribe

I'm starting to work on pub/sub messaging internally, and there's a chance that over time, the format of a specific type of message will change.  Is there a standard approach or pattern for handling this?  If I'm listening for a message with a topic of "user-message", should I simply message the topic via something like "user-message-v1", "user-message-v2", etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I would simply add a property "version" to the message payload.